# Project Euler 8: Largest product in a series in Functional Programming (FP)

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I wanted to practice functional programming (fp) without using any library but using vanilla JS only. So I took a problem from Project Euler:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

My solution in FP:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  const INPUT =    '7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450';

  const parser = (maxProduct, number) => {
    const SIZE = 13;
    const multiply = (acc, val) => acc * val;
    const product = number
      .slice(0, SIZE)
      .split('')
      .reduce(multiply);
    const latestMaxProduct = product > maxProduct ? product : maxProduct;

    return number.length < SIZE ?
      latestMaxProduct :
      parser(latestMaxProduct, number.slice(1));
  };
  const solution = parser(0, INPUT);

  console.log("solution ", solution);
})();
```

Is there a better way to write it in FP (without any libraries and with vanilla JS only)? Also any improvement suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: I have nothing for the FP aspect of it, but the style is inconsistent. Some `const` are, according to standards, all uppercase, but the rest are not.

Comment: `SIZE` and `INPUT` are capital letters because they stay the same at every iteration. Others are `function`s. And others are indeed constant-variables, but different ones - newly created at every recursion. This is the distinction I wanted to make between `const` with capital letters and `const` with standard letters. @Carles Alcolea

Comment: Instead of `(function() {})()`you could use a simple block `{}`.

Comment: The products of 13 digits are still within the range where you can perform integer division without having to worry about precision errors. So a less complex solution would probably find those products by iterating through all digits only once, multiplying with the next digit and dividing by the digit seen 13 iterations ago. You could squeeze this into a reduce accumulator, but I'd probably write a generator function for that and a `function max(iterable)`.

Comment: For those downvoting this question: Please provide an explanation so I don't repeat the mistake twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes about your code:

- `(function () {`. Is this old-style wrapping really needed? Isn't this a node.js script?
- You parsed `INPUT` manually from the question. You should probably leave the input as similar as possible to how it's stated and do the parsing programatically.
- `const multiply = (acc, val) => acc * val;`: The variable names reveal how the function is used; instead, keep it generic: `const multiply = (x, y) => x * y;`. Consider also creating the abstraction `product`, the product of all numbers in an array.
- `parser(latestMaxProduct, number.slice(1));` You should use recursive calls as a last resort, only when higher-level abstractions (map, filter, reduce, ...) are not enough.
- I'd separate generic functions from the specific code used in the problem. Re-using generic abstractions is one the fundamental principles of FP.

I'd write:

```
const range = (start, end) => Array.from(new Array(end - start), (x, i) => i + start);
const groupsOf = (xs, n) => range(0, xs.length - n + 1).map(i =>  xs.slice(i, i + n));
const product = xs => xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc * x, 1);
const maximum = xs => Math.max(...xs);

const euler8 = () => {
  const unparsedDigits = `
    73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
    96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
    ...
  `;
  const groupSize = 13;

  const digits = unparsedDigits.replace(/[^\d]/g, "").split("").map(c => parseInt(c));
  return maximum(groupsOf(digits, groupSize).map(product));
}

console.log(euler8());
```

Comment: May downvoters comment so the answer can be improved?